# Excel VBA - Change userform height and width on click event

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In Excel 365 a userform named "frmVorlage" is used.

A label named lblTtlMaximize is intended to change the size of the userform on click.
This Userform starts with width = 455,25 and height = 1023,75 (set in the properties box)

Following code does only change the position, but not the height neither the width:

```
Private Sub lblTtlMaximize_Click()
        frmVorlage.Height = 1080
        frmVorlage.Width = 1920
        frmVorlage.Top = 0
        frmVorlage.Left = 0
End Sub
```

- Made sure the sub is executed by putting in "Debug.Print frmVorlage.Height" => Shows 1080 but the actual height of the userform is not changed
- If i put the same code in the initialize event it works and the Userform starts with width 1920 and height 1080
- Me.Width and Me.Height does not work either

I am out of ideas how to fix this, since the .Top and .Left properties are changed on click but the .Height and .Width are not...

Comment: You can use `Me` inside a form's code module to refer to the form itself.  eg `Me.Height = 1080`

Comment: In fact you would *WANT* to set `Me.Height` etc to affect the current instance of the form as opposed to the actual `frmVorlage` class's Height.

Comment: I tried `Me.Height` instead of `frmVorlage.Height` in former tries. The same problem still persists. I added this in my question. But as mentioned the frmVorlage.Top position is changed even though i use the frmVorlage Class. So using Me. does not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: `Me.Width/Height` works for me - seems like there's something about your form setup we're not mimicking.

Comment: I will try the code on a newly created workbook/userform after the weekend. Thanks for the hints so far.

Comment: The issue was a Windowhandle wich set a Window Shape in the Userform_Activate event. So the Userform was indeed resized, but the Shape that showed the Userform was not. Resetting the WIndow Shape helped. So sorry about the confusion.... Ill Mark Archerbirds Answer as the solution, since it shows the code that should be used. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the form correctly, that is to say you let the user work with a `new` instance of your `frmVorlage` form, you will want to set the instance properties using the `Me` keyword.

```
Sub ShowMyForm()
    Dim uf As frmVorlage
    Set uf = New frmVorlage
    
    uf.Show
End Sub
```

**Form Code**

```
Private Sub lblTtlMaximize_Click()
        Me.Height = 1080
        Me.Width = 1920
        Me.Top = 0
        Me.Left = 0
End Sub
```

If you set `frmVorlage` properties, you are actually just setting the form class's properties. You can see that if you show the form class (`frmVorlage.Show`), rather than an instance of the form, then your OnClick method works as you have it.

Comment: I tried using your code with and showing the Form with the ShowMyForm Sub as a new instance. But the problem Still persists. Thats why i am out of ideas.

Comment: very strange, works on my machine

Comment: I will try the code on a newly created userform after the weekend. Thanks for the hints so far.

Comment: This works. The Problem was another one, as described in the questions comments. Thank you.